# Syntax or logical error in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable number of promotional items (`panels`) that are in a sliding belt, that should be set to the width of a panel (`300px`) multiplied with the amount of panels.

It alerts the correct beltsize. With fixed numbers the slider works too. I suspect the error to be in the `if/else if` part. I am not even sure this is valid Javascript Syntax.

Any hint is appreciated.

```
   $(window).ready(function(){  
        var whichpanel = 1;
        var panels = $(".panel").length;
        var beltsize = panels*300;
        $('.belt').css({'width':beltsize});
    });

    $(window).ready(function promoslider(){
        if (panels>whichpanel){
            $('.belt').delay(7000).animate({'left':'-=300'}, 500);
            whichpanel += 1;    
        }
        else if (panels=whichpanel){
            $('.belt').delay(7000).animate({'left':'0'}, 500);
            whichpanel = 1;
        }   
        setTimeout(promoslider, 0);

    });
    promoslider;
```

UPDATE! Here is the code that works for me now (http://jsfiddle.net/zr5Nd/10/):

```
$(window).ready(function () {
var whichpanel = 1;
var panels = $(".panel").length;
var beltsize = panels * 300;
$('.belt').css({
    'width': beltsize
});

function movingdiv() {
    if (panels > whichpanel) {
        //alert('Panels:' + panels + '/whichpanel:' + whichpanel);
        $('.belt').delay(1000).animate({
            'margin-left': '-=300px'
        }, 500);
        whichpanel += 1;

    } else if (panels == whichpanel) {
        //alert('Panels:' + panels + '/whichpanel:' + whichpanel);
        $('.belt').delay(1000).animate({
            'margin-left': '0'
        }, 500*panels);
        whichpanel = 1;

    } else {
        alert('3');
    }
    setTimeout(movingdiv, 0);
}

setTimeout(movingdiv, 0);
```

});

Comment: I changed promoslider; to promoslider(); put it inside the ready function too, also changed the operator, but it still does not move. There must be one or more additional errors ...

Comment: Here is a fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/Coffeehouse/zr5Nd/3/ since it still does not work

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the equality/identity operators (`==`/`===`) instead of the assignment operator `=` in your `else if` statement, e.g.

```
else if (panels == whichpanel){
   $('.belt').delay(7000).animate({'left':'0'}, 500);
   whichpanel = 1;
}
```

Also, I believe `promoslider;` is supposed to be `promoslider();`.

Comment: Ok, I changed both (though it worked before with the brackets for promoslider). But there must be an additional error, because it still does not move.

Comment: @user2164882 Can you make a little jsFiddle with your HTML/jQuery? I need your HTML. I can fix it quickly then.

Comment: It works now: http://jsfiddle.net/zr5Nd/10/ The reason seemed to be that they needed to be in the same window ready function, also the 'left' did not work, so I had to use 'margin-left'. I assume that is because of some missing or wrong position attributes and the floating divs, because it worked with just 'left' in my live system.

Comment: @user2164882 Yep, I tried putting both inside the same window ready yesterday, but didn't do the 'left' part, so it didn't work :p Can I update the full code as the answer? Just for future readers who may not read our comments.

Comment: Sure you can. I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: @user2164882 I'm posting it as a "community wiki" answer below, would be good if you accept that wiki answer for future users. Glad it's fixed!

Answer (score 0):

use `panels === whichpanel`  instead of   `panels=whichpanel`

variables `whichpanel`, `panels` have lost their `scope` in the `if/else if` part.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the call of `promoslider` into `$(window).ready` as well, as the function does not yet exist otherwise. Plus you have to do the call this way `promoslider()`, `promoslider` alone will not result in a call.
And of course you have to use the equals-operator `==` instead of the assign-operator `=` in your `if else`-statement.